# Palabras no permitidas al final de una oración

Tags: gramática, sintaxis

En editorial, ¿cuáles son las palabras que deben evitarse al final de la oración? Trabajando en una editorial los correctores marcaban todas las preposiciones como erróneas al final de una oración, especialmente las de una o dos sílabas.

¿Además de esta, existe alguna otra regla específica del idioma español?

Hay unas reglas que creo son universales, tales como evitar el corte de palabra en una sílaba o las repetición de palabras al inicio o fin de la oración.

Comment: ¿Podrías ponernos algún ejemplo concreto de frase cuya terminación fuera corregida? El caso de las preposición parece obvio, dado que su propio nombre "pre-posición" indica que anteceden a un término con el que forman grupo sintáctico. Si se omite dicho término y la preposición queda al final de frase, sonaría como si la frase quedara en suspenso, inconclusa.

Comment: Hola @Charlie, sí, lo de las preposiciones lo tengo claro, solo quiero saber si existe alguna otra regla a tener en cuenta en Español. Hice un edit en la pregunta.

Comment: No me viene a la cabeza ninguna preposición de más de dos sílabas... Entiendo que la pregunta la generalizas indicando si hay algunas categorías gramaticales específicas (además, quizá, de las preposiciones) que no se considere correcto que aparezcan a final de oración.

Comment: @fedorqui Durante y mediante

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es tan extensa como lo es "la gramática española" la cual consigna las "reglas universales" de lo que esta permitido y de lo que no. Todas las reglas de la gramática aplican como respuesta por lo que creo que la pregunta es tan amplia que cae en el off-topic.

Comment: No creas, dentro del área editorial hay algunas reglas a seguir bastante elementales y en ocasiones estrictas. De hecho en la pregunta hago referencia que hasta donde sé es la única regla para finales de oraciones. Por eso pregunto si existe otra. Una sola regla no creo que sea algo muy extenso.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta es sobre prácticas editoriales y no propiamente sobre el idioma. Si se tratara de una duda sobre una cuestión específica sería posible contestarla, pero no en esta forma tan general.

Comment: Cierro como demasiado genérica. Tal y como se comentó por parte de diferentes personas, estás refiriéndote a un campo algo extenso y no reglado como son las editoriales. Te animo a editar tu pregunta para ceñirla a algún caso, por ejemplo a lo que recomienda la RAE.